# data-toggle="buttons" bootstrap radio button not being recognized in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to hide a div(**#asideform**) when I click a radio button and it works if I remove the **data-toggle="buttons"** from the main div (which is needed for styling), but not if I let it there.

Am I expressing it correctly in the JavaScript code?

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group form-group col-xs-6" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label style="float: left; margin-bottom: 0;">Owns 50% +</label>
    <br>
    <label style="margin-top: 1%" class="btn btn-primary active rdio50">
        <input type="radio" name="rdio50" id="foyes" name="foyes" autocomplete="off"  checked> Yes
    </label>
    <label style="margin-top: 1%" class="btn btn-primary rdio50">
        <input type="radio" name="rdio50" id="fono" name="fono" autocomplete="off"> No
    </label>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $("input[name='rdio50']").click(function () {
        if ($("#fono").is(":checked")) {
            $("#asideform").show();
        } else {
            $("#asideform").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you load a demo script from bootstrap to your page, and set `data-toggle` attribute with `button` as it's value, then a function will be bound to this element by that demo scripts.

Comment: if you want a button-styled element, just add `btn btn-primary` or `btn btn-default` (or other style) to the class of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example, I think this is what you mean.
[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/1yejaxvk/)

```
$('.btn-group').click(function() {
   if($('#fono').is(':checked')) { $('#asideform').show(); }

   else{ $('#asideform').hide();}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When use `data-toggle="buttons"`, you click target is the `label` of radio  that's why your `click` event on `input` radio will not fire.

So, just use `change` event to watch `radio` value, even label click will fire input change, then it worked.

So, replace

```
$("input[name='rdio50']").click(function () {...});
```

with

```
$("input[name='rdio50']").change(function () {...});
```

**Here is the working example:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[name='rdio50']").change(function() {
    if ($("#fono").is(":checked")) {
      $("#asideform").show();
    } else {
      $("#asideform").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="btn-group form-group col-xs-6" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label style="float: left; margin-bottom: 0;">Owns 50% +</label>
  <br>
  <label style="margin-top: 1%" class="btn btn-primary active rdio50">
    <input type="radio" name="rdio50" id="foyes" name="foyes" value="yes" autocomplete="off" checked>Yes
  </label>
  <label style="margin-top: 1%" class="btn btn-primary rdio50">
    <input type="radio" name="rdio50" id="fono" name="fono" value="no" autocomplete="off">No
  </label>
</div>

<div id="asideform">
  this is the asideform
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys but Alberto's answer solved my problem.

Comment: :)   figure out why it does not work is also important.